# OpenFileDialog class not working properly in c++

Tags: c++, openfiledialog

I want to show the file name that is opened by OpenFileDialog but it sends the wrong text into title bar. I hace changed the character set of the project but it did not help. here is my code :

OpenFileDialog .h :

```
    class OpenFileDialog  
    {
    public:
        OpenFileDialog(){};
        void CreateOpenFileDialog(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR Title, LPCWSTR InitialDirectory, LPCWSTR Filter, int FilterIndex);
        ~OpenFileDialog(){};
        LPCWSTR result=L"";
    };
```

OpenFileDialog .cpp :

```
      void OpenFileDialog::CreateOpenFileDialog(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR Title, LPCWSTR InitialDirectory, LPCWSTR Filter, int FilterIndex)
       {
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    TCHAR szFile[MAX_PATH];
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = Filter;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = FilterIndex;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = Title;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = InitialDirectory;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;


    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
    {
         result = ofn.lpstrFile;
    }
    else
    {
        result = L"Empty";
    }
}
```

and in windows procedure in WM_COMMAND :

```
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_FILE_OPEN)
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd;
                ofd.CreateOpenFileDialog(hwnd, L"Test", L"C:\\", L"All files(*.*)\0*.*\0TextFiles(*.txt)\0*.txt\0", 2);
                SetWindowText(hwnd, ofd.result);
            }
            break;
        }
```

thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function  `CreateOpenFileDialog()`,  the buffer for storing the file name is a local array `szFile[MAX_PATH]`.  You initialize the `lpstrFile = szFile` in the `ofn` structure, making sure that the `GetOpenFileName()` puts the result of user entry at the right place.

The problem is that as soon as you return from `CreateOpenFileDialog()`, its local variables are destroyed, including the buffer containing the file name. Hence, the `result`pointer that you've set with `result = ofn.lpstrFile;` then points to an invalid memory location.

You can solve this by allocating the buffer directly in `result` in the `OpenFileDialog`  constructor  (or making it an array),  and  using this pointer directly with `ofn.lpstrFile = buffer;`